# Web scraper not working in Beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here's my code, a simple request to pull in a Chinese website:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://gujia.oilchem.net/l/p.do?productName=%E6%B1%BD%E6%B2%B9&area=%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=(20,20), verify=False)

print(response.content)
```

but I keep on getting this trace back/error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('F:/Python/WebScrapes/OilChemScrapes.py', wdir='F:/Python/WebScrapes')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tliu210\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tliu210\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "F:/Python/WebScrapes/OilChemScrapes.py", line 15, in 
>       response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=(20,20), verify=False)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tliu210\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
>   line 72, in get
>       return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tliu210\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
>   line 58, in request
>       return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tliu210\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 508, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tliu210\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
>   line 618, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\tliu210\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
>   line 490, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
>
> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote
>   end closed connection without response',))

I even tried different versions of Chrome in the header

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The `timeout` and `header` parameters are not needed, and the exception is not because of the Beautiful Soup. Just remove `timeout` and `header` and it works on my laptop (Python 3.5+)

Comment: Tks~ it still doesn't work on my machines. Maybe it is my company's firewall. I'll check with the IT team this week.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, problem in the wrong User-agent header. From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), header must looks something like that:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
```

Comment: I copied the headers in the documentation link above but still no luck. Maybe it is my company's firewall settings. Tks~

Comment: Well, I tryed to run this code on my computer and it works. Perhaps, it's firewall settings... In a pinch you can try to run this code on another computer (network) or VPS.